# Pass arguments to Ruby when running Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

When I run `rails server`, `rails console`, `rails runner`, etc., I want to pass some command-line switches to the Ruby binary. (In my case it's JRuby and I want to make sure Java starts up with more memory, but this question seems like it could apply to any Ruby implementation.) Surprisingly I can't find any documentation about this. Anyone know how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
  jruby --args -S rails ...
```

Comment: That makes sense. JRuby will also answer to `ruby`, at least under rvm, so I can don't even have to hard-code the jruby binary here. And my next planned question was "How do I pass arguments to Ruby through Rake," but now I don't have to ask it. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Use the `JRUBY_OPTS` env variable as in

```
JRUBY_OPTS="-J-Xmn512m" rails server
```

Comment: That will do it! Upvoting, but I'm going to accept @rogerdpack's answer since it is more general.

Comment: But mine is more convenient, as you can store this stuff in your shell ;-)